# $H_1,H_2$ distinct subgroups of $G$ each of order $2$ , $H$ be smallest containing both , what is order of $H$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $H_1,H_2$ be two distinct subgroups of finite group $G$ each of order $2$. Let $H$ be the smallest subgroup containing $H_1$ and $H_2$ . Then is it necessary that  order of $H$ is amongst $2,4,8?$

I think that this is not true if we consider $S_3$ and $H_1=\{(1),(12)\}$ , $H_2=\{(1),(23)\}$ then smallest subgroup will be $S_3$ itself!

Comment: Yes, this is a valid counterexample to the statement.

Comment: As a matter of fact, given any positive integer $n$, there exists a group in which there are elements $x$ and $y$, each of order $2$, whose product $xy$ has order $n$.

Comment: Alexander, great remark! One up from me!

Comment: My question is, with same conditions mentioned above in the question, will order(H) be bounded? (i.e) whatever the group may be, the order of H will be less than a certain number?. can we deduce that?

Answer (score 4):

If $H_1$ or $H_2$ is *normal*, then your statement is true, in fact in that case $H=H_1H_2$ and $|H_1H_2|=4$. In general, the **set** $H_1H_2$ has 4 elements, since $|H_1H_2|=|H_1||H_2|/|H_1 \cap H_2|=2.2/1=4$, and of course $H_1H_2 \subseteq H$. So $H$ has *at least* 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

$H_1$={$1,a$}, $H_2=${$1,b$}. As the subgroups are distinct $a$ not equal to $b$. |$H_1\cup H_2|=3$. Note that $a,b$ are self inverse elements in $G$. Again if $H$ is the smallest group containing $H_1\cup H_2$ then $ab \in H$. 
Case 1. If $G$ abelian then $ab$ is self inverse element. so |H|=4.
Case 2. If $G$ is not abelian $b^-1a^-1\in H$ . So |H|=5.